# Is azure TenantId equivalent to azure log analytics WorkspaceId?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to get from azure some information about computers.

What I want to get back is the list of Azure wokapceId, SourceComputerId, Resource group for each machine.

I used the ServiceMapComputer_CL table in log analytics to get this data.

I noticed that the workspaceId and TenantId are the same but I need to confirm this as there is nothing in the documentation that documents this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are not the same thing.

workspaceId is used to identified the log analytics workspace, details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/manage-access#view-workspace-details).

TenantId is used to identified Azure AD, details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant#work-and-school-accounts-or-personal-microsoft-accounts).